# Moving a window that can't be dragged by the title bar?

Tags: windows-7, window-manager

I have Fallout Collection and I am trying to run it windowed because of the low resolution. When I change the mode to windowed via the .ini file, however, it starts the game with the window shoved into the upper left corner of my screen.

Clicking the title bar of the window just clicks back into the game program. So how can I move it to the center of my screen? I am using Windows 7 professional 64-bit.

Answer (score 5):

I've always used Alt-Space in this type of scenario.  That will bring up a menu where you can select "Move", then use the arrow keys to move the window around.  Press Enter to lock it into position.

Comment: After you've pressed an arrow key once you can use the mouse to move the window. This is handy if the window is off the screen or a long way from where you want it.

Comment: There are some windows where Alt-Space does nothing. I'm not sure when this happens though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the software "AutoHotKey", which has a WinMove function.

```
WinMove, 100,100
```

Would move the currently active window to (100,100), and

```
WinMove, Window Title,,100,100
```

Would move [Window Title] to 100,100.

So, for example:

```
#q::WinMove, 100,100
```

When pressed while FO Trilogy is active would move the window to 100,100, rather than 0,0.