# Can't move a window by dragging its title bar in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drag-and-drop

In Windows 10 I have a window that can normally be dragged around the screen and snapped to the screen edges. Today, it won't move with the mouse although other programs still do.

This is similar to [Moving a window that can't be dragged by the title bar?](https://superuser.com/q/136886/148107), although that question seems to be for a program where dragging has never worked.

I want to be able to drag it again as I could yesterday. The solutions on the answer above are not satisfactory as they are too cumbersome to do repeatedly.

Restarting the computer will probably fix it, but it seems like overkill for such a  small issue. Is there some window-move-locking feature I've inadvertently turned on?

Comment: I am uncertain as to why restarting is such a hardship. I suggest restarting, running basic repairs, restarting again and test.   From an admin command prompt, run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth followed by SFC /SCANNOW.  See if, after doing the above (15 minutes work) the window is dragging again

Comment: Depends on how many folders and programs one has running how big a pain it is to restart, it a pain for me, I would rather mow the yard, its much easier.

Comment: Correct Moab. @John Only about a third of my applications can restart themselves to the same state when I reboot the computer. I usually have multiple command prompts open and shutting one of them downs loses its command history.

Comment: I suspect that you must be behind in updates because the most recent Windows Updates occurred within the last 72 hours and both sets required restarts.

Comment: @John That's three days ago. My problem started less than a day ago.